# How to resize an xrandr monitor created with `xrandr --setmonitor`

Tags: xrandr

I can create virtual monitors with `xrandr` using `xrandr --setmonitor`, which is useful to e.g. split an ultrawide display into multiple virtual monitors. However, I can't figure out how to resize an existing virtual monitor. E.g. suppose I've created 2 virtual monitors as followed:

```shell
xrandr --setmonitor eDP-1-1 [dimensions] eDP1
xrandr --setmonitor eDP-1-2 [dimensions] none
```

And now I want to resize `eDP-1-2`. How can I do this?

The only option I've found so far is to remove the monitor (using `xrandr --delmonitor`) and then recreate it, but this loses the window configuration on the target monitor. Can I resize the monitor **without** removing and recreating it?